# Using MVC C# and Razor; How can I replace a partial page section at Runtime?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I have a partial page of text generated from a database that will display in a partial view. I have an Edit link that shows up if the user has rights.
I want to click Edit and then replace the current partial page in the

```
<div> current partial page </div>
```

With a different partial view.

I was looking here [MVC with Razor: how to refresh partial page on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844222/mvc-with-razor-how-to-refresh-partial-page-on-click)

That is about refreshing - I want to replace. 
Can someone provide some assistance as to what I need to do in order to replace, after the edit I want to restore back to the original division with the updated data.

**EDIT**

I have this MVC action link in my code @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) and I am using MVC .. as some have pointed out in answers - it looks like javascript is required in order to do the work on the client side.

Golda's answer seems to point me in the right direction .. and I will try to implement that and see how it works out. Although I am curious how you get inline preview with editing at the same time - like in this text box the preview data is being filled in as I type. and I would like to know how this is done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace html element with ajax response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527586/how-to-replace-html-element-with-ajax-response)

Comment: On the client a "partial page" is just HTML

Comment: @Liam my partial page has a model and is populated with that model - I am basically editing a form of text and want to be able to edit and then display those edits back again with out doing alot of reloading ..

Answer (score 0):

Provide an ID for div. In the below code `currentDiv` is an ID of div.

```
<div id='currentDiv'> current partial page </div>
```

The below is a Jquery to replace div content

```
$("#editLink").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Controller/Action',
        data: { parameter: parameter},
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'html',
        cache: false,
        async: false
    })
        .success(function (result) {
            $('#currentDiv').html(result);
        });
});
```

Code for controller

```
public ActionResult Action(int parameter)
{
    return PartialView("partialView", parameter);
}
```

**Updated Answer**

```
<a id="editLink" data-itemid="@item.Id"> Click Here </a>
```

You can receive the ID using data attribute

```
$("#editLink").click(function () {
  var itemID = $(this).data("itemid");
  ---
  ---
  ---
});
```

*Note: The **data-itemid** should be in lower case*

Comment: so #editLink is the 'name' of my edit link ?  And URL: url: '/Controller/Action' is the partial with controller action that I would like to change out to.. just verifying before I insert code into project - but I will give this a whirl.

Comment: @Ken, #editLink is ID of the edit link and you are correct about the URL

Comment: Right now in my cshtml code I have @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) so instead of that I will need a regular html link ? for data: I use my new { id = item.Id } (how to pas that in item Id in to the function ? function(int Id) ??